# Apple Mach-O Linker Error - Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_UISceneWillEnterForegroundNotification" and "___isPlatformVersionAtLeast"

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, intercom

I am using https://github.com/tinycreative/react-native-intercom and went through the installation there and https://developers.intercom.com/installing-intercom/docs/ios-installation

This worked fine for a while and just started all of a sudden.

[image]

```
  "_UISceneWillEnterForegroundNotification", referenced from:
      +[ICMBridge load] in Intercom(ICMBridge.o)
  "___isPlatformVersionAtLeast", referenced from:
      -[IntercomSDK_IntercomConversationCollectionViewController insetsForAccessoryView] in Intercom(IntercomConversationCollectionViewController.o)
      +[IntercomSDK_ITBUpload createUploadForMediaAsset:completion:] in Intercom(ITBUpload.o)
      +[IntercomSDK_ITBUpload processImageDataForUpload:mediaAsset:info:imageUploadDataUTI:completion:] in Intercom(ITBUpload.o)
      -[IntercomSDK_IIMInputAccessoryView createConstraints] in Intercom(IIMInputAccessoryView.o)
      -[IntercomSDK_IIMInputButtonContainerView createConstraints] in Intercom(IIMInputButtonContainerView.o)
      -[IntercomSDK_IIMMediaViewController updateCollectionViewContentInsets] in Intercom(IIMMediaViewController.o)
      -[IntercomSDK_IIMMediaViewController layoutExpandButton] in Intercom(IIMMediaViewController.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

On 12-09-2019, Intercom released sdk version 5.5.0, which supports iOS 13.

https://github.com/intercom/intercom-ios/releases/tag/5.5.0

`UISceneWillEnterForegroundNotification` and `isPlatformVersionAtLeast` are in iOS SDK 13, so would require Xcode 11 beta. I think you are getting the error because you are using an earlier Xcode version like Xcode 10.3 etc.

Ideally Intercom should have conditionally supported iOS 13 stuff so that the code wouldn't have broken on iOS sdk versions earlier than 13.0

Comment: Thanks Umer! I was able to build successfully after upgrading to the Beta version of Xcode found here: https://developer.apple.com/download/

Comment: Thanks! `pod 'Intercom', '~> 5.4.1'` does solve the problem. Sent a note to guys from Intercom, maybe they will pay attention.

Comment: Brian here from Intercom. As of Intercom iOS SDK 5.5.0, Xcode 11 is required. We do have conditional support for iOS 13 however, we cannot conditionally support versions of Xcode.